# Bluetooth: How to read messages from "Message Notification Service" (MNS) from MAP? QT

Tags: qt, sockets, bluetooth, notifications

I am writing a QT 5 application on my laptop (Debian 8) where i want to be notified if a new SMS is available on my phone (OnePlus One, Android 5.1).

I managed to register the MAP service and read SMS manually. For this i created a socket. When there is new data available the `readyRead()` signal should be called. This works fine for getting SMS manually. Over the same socket i register the Message Notification Service.

The problem i have is, that the  `readyRead()` signal is never emitted when a new message arraives. To monitor the data flow i use wireshark. Wireshark shows the event. So the smartphone sends the event to laptop, but not to socket which starts the connection request?

The information for registration i got from the (MAP) specification here: https://www.bluetooth.org/docman/handlers/DownloadDoc.ashx?doc_id=409110

My idea was that smartphone and laptop create a new socket, but not sure. And even when, i have no idea how to access this socket with QT.

Can anybody help? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Over the same socket i register the Message Notification Service.

MAS and MNS should be  two RFCOMM links, i.e. you may have two sockets, one for MAS client and the other one for MNS server.
You may refer the figure 6.3 at MAP spec 1.1 section 6.4.2.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. As i understood how it works after reading specification again, i use my MAP socket for registration the notification. Then a new connection is created, a socket on the smartphone? How can i access this socket now. The UUID for MNS is not given when searching services.

Comment: in this scenario, your PC would be the MNS server and the phone would be the MNS client, which means the phone will initialize the connection to your PC. Steps like this: 1)you register the SDP of MNS server on your PC;2)your PC connect phone with MAS;3)your phone discovery your PC's SDP, if found MNS server supported, phone will connect MNS; 4)after MNS connection, your PC register notification; once new message comes, phone will notify PC to fetch it from phone.

Comment: thank you, this helped me a lot. I managed to get the socket connection in my QT programm. To check the traffic i use wireshark. Before there was a 'Success' message, now there is no. Also the map-reports are not sended. I looked in the log of the laptop and the smartphone. The QluetoothServer i use, listens at port / channel 1. This is how i call it:     `serviceInfo = rfcommServer->listen( QBluetoothUuid(QBluetoothUuid::MessageNotificationServer), "MNS");` Any idea how to fix this, so i get the 'success' message and depending on it (?) the map-reports? Thanks

Comment: Did you registered the MNS SDP record on your PC? then phone can connect the right channel. Let's split the MAS and MNS; first you need make sure MAS connected; after that phone will check your MNS SDP record and find the right channel then connect to your PC.

Comment: Everything is working now. Because the message notification service is the only (my first) profile, where the smartphone requests the computer for a service, i forget / oversee the fact, that the computer has to send the "Success" message. Now everything is fine. Thank you for your help :) The only thing is that the smartphone resets / disconnects the connection after a while, but i am not sure if it is because this.

Comment: You've done a good job actually, the MAP profile is one of the difficult profile on Bluetooth, but if you understand the MAP you will go smartly understand PBAP/OPP and other profiles over OBEX/RFCOMM.  to see why the link disconnected, you can check the btsnoop.log on your mobile phone if it is an Android phone.